# Java Play - difference between jdbc and javaJdbc library dependencies

Tags: java, playframework

Is there any difference between `jdbc` and `javaJdbc` library dependency in Java Play framework 2.8.x that you declare inside `build.sbt` ?

For example, in [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/AccessingAnSQLDatabase#Configuring-JDBC-connection-pools) autor uses

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc
)
```

However, I've seen successfully using only `jdbc`

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Play provides a plugin for managing JDBC connection pools. You can configure as many databases as you need.

As per [documentation](https://ibb.co/NrnCYTw) of Play Framework, it provides two examples:

- the first one for java;
- the second one for scala.

It provides two identical APIs depending on the language you choose.
For instance, if you use `enablePlugins(PlayJava)` then the appropriate dependency is `javaJdbc`.

Similar to other package structures, it makes an only a difference in the imports

**java**

```
import play.db.*;
```

vs

**scala**

```
import play.api.db._
```